# Canvas lines behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a quick JS snippet to draw a background into a div using canvas consisting of diagonal lines (SO COMPLEX!), this seemed pretty simple to me but when I checked my [**implementation**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t3xX/20/) the lines seem to get cut off about 20% from the bottom and a few of them seem to terminate early.

My draw function is relatively simple:

```
function draw() {
  for(var j = 0; j <= canvas.width; j = j + gridPixelSize) {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(j, 0)
      ctx.lineTo(0, j)
      ctx.lineWidth = 1.5
      ctx.closePath()
      ctx.stroke()
  }
}
```

This is my first foray into using Canvas so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

(Bonus screenshot)
[image: so much failure]

Comment: In case you can't figure it out, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wns7/) an implementation that will give the desired output. It's not a solution to your problem, though.

Comment: The closePath() is likely unnecessary. It draws a line to the beginning of the path, so all it does in this case is drawing the line twice in opposite directions.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for your problem becomes apparent when you do not hide the canvas:

[image: Above fiddle with the canvas visible]

As you see, you don't draw lines on the full canvas and the canvas doesn't fit the div, so it is cropped horizontally and repeated vertically.

1. When you want to change the actual working space in pixels of the canvas, do not use CSS styling. This influences the output, but not the actual internal resolution. When you want a canvas of a specific pixel size, define the width and height in the canvas tag: `<canvas width="173" height="200"></canvas>`
2. Draw lines over the full size of the canvas by using `j <= canvas.height + canvas.width`. You could maybe improve performance a bit by not drawing lines outside of the canvas space and instead using separate loops for the upper-left and lower-right half, but that would make the code more complex. Also, I made the experience that most cases of off-canvas drawing is practically free in most browsers.

Here is [an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6E794/3/).